# Address of a coordinate in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7

I want to get the address of particular coordinate in iOS. I am using `CLLocationManager`.

Can I get the address of coordinate? I am testing my app in simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try GeoReverse code of apple API